# How can I use BitBucket repository as source in cloud function 2nd gen?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions

Define the directory where source code is stored in the source repository

Hi, I am creating a cloud function 2nd generation and I am using code from another source repository.
I am using Terraform and the module *"google_cloudfunctions2_function"*. Currently I am using Cloud Source Repository as my *"repo_source"*. But I would like to use a BitBucket repository. I can not mirror Cloud Source Repository and BitBucket (as described here: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository?hl=de) because BitBucket is hosted from an internal organisation.

```
repo_source = {

  project_id  = var.project_id

  repo_name = "MY_REPO"

  branch_name   = "master"

}
```

Is there any possibility to use BitBucket source repo in *"repo_source"* or with any other key word?

I can not mirror Cloud Source Repository and BitBucket (as described here: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository?hl=de) because BitBucket is hosted from an internal organisation.

Answer (score 1):

I see two potential solutions. Both involve pushing the code in some way

You can either sync the BitBucket repository yourself. E.g. create a BitBucket pipeline, that pushes your code to the Cloud Source Repo.

Or alternatively you use the `storage_source` block from [cloudfunctions2_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function).
That requires that your code is uploaded as a zip file to a Cloud Storage Bucket. So you again need a BitBucket Pipeline, that zips and uploads your code.

Comment: do you have any template of how to create this?

Comment: No, I've never used BitBucket Pipelines before.

Answer (score 0):

**Capabilities:**
You can connect repositories from Bitbucket Data Center and Bitbucket Server

Cloud Build repositories (1st gen) - YES

Cloud Build repositories (2nd gen) - NO

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/repositories#repositories_1st_gen_and_repositories_2nd_gen